# Importing Orange Pickled Models in Jupyter

Tags: machine-learning, orange

I am doing some testing with geoscience data and a few supervised methods in Orange. I have been saving these models as pickle models, but I would like to import them in my Jupyter notebook. How can I do this? Do I need to import a specific library?

Thanks.